# Java regex ability to handle nested matches separately

Tags: java, android, regex

I completely can't figure out how to write pattern, to achieve nested fractions in latex with my regex.

Here is couple sample user inputs:

```
"fractionx+3over5moveout+2"
"fractionfractionx+1over7moveoutover3moveout+1", 
"fractionfractionfractionx+3over3moveoutoverx+2moveoutover7moveout+1".
```

Here's my regex code(I made partial versions):

```
\\Final version with closing "moveout" phrase
regexPattern = Pattern.compile(fraction(?<upper>.*?)over(?<lower>.*?)moveout);
regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(userInput);
mathFormulaInLaTeX = regexMatcher.replaceAll(\\frac{${upper}} {${lower}});

\\Starting version without "over" keyword
regexPattern = Pattern.compile(fraction(?<upper>.*));
regexMatcher = regexPattern.matcher(userInput);
mathFormulaInLaTeX = regexMatcher.replaceAll(\\frac{${upper}} {});
```

With the following inputs I get results:

Input: "fractionx+3over5moveout+2"

(The final regex version works fine with only one fraction)
[image]

Input: "fractionfractionx+1"

(Starting version without "over" keyword with nested fractions not working properly)
[image]

Input: "fractionfractionx+1over7moveoutover3moveout+1"

(The final regex version with nested fractions adds moveout word)
[image]

Input: "fractionfractionfractionx+3over3moveoutoverx+2moveoutover7moveout+1"

(Completly misclassified)

[image]

Is there a neat pattern solution for any number of nested fractions, to get rid of "moveout" word displaying and make nested fraction like this:

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Using regex to parse nested markup is a bad idea. You probably want to use your own recursive parser and use regex only on single elements (or not at all) once parsed.

Answer (score 2):

As has been said in the comments, this is not a good idea. Mathematical expressions, even simple ones, are not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) - they are a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). While it is hypothetically possible to [*match*](https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html) an arbitrary math expression with modern regex engines, to attempt to *parse* one with them is foolhardy at best. I would recommend either [rolling your own lexical analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848207/making-a-lexical-analyzer) or using something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).